# JSON & angularjs. Filter an array by ID (and not by index)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

How can i filter this JSON by an element (in this case the id) without using the index?

```
     ABC: [{
 ID: home,
 elementsHome: [
       {
       el1: x,
       el2: y},
       {
       el3: d,
       el4: s}]
  },
  {
  ID: payments,
  elementsPaymets: etc...
  }];
```

An html with an ng-repeat like this doesn't work: ng-repeat: item in ABC.element2 | filter: {id:"good"}. The only way is re-write ABC this way ABC[0] but this is what I want to avoid.

Thanks

Comment: Could you not use `Array.prototype.filter`, and filter by the ID property?

Comment: can you show me an example about this? I'm still a junior angularjs :P

Comment: if you don't use ES6 .. and you're using es5 ..try LODASH .. method _.filter() or also _.find() would fit for you

Comment: What is ```ABC.element2```? If you filter ```<div ng-repeat="item in ABC | filter:{id:'good'}">{{item.id}}  </div>``` this works.

Comment: Dario (italian?) the problem is that i want use id just like a filter but i don't want to show it. I need to show the elements in element2.

Comment: than you need `Array.prototype.map` instead of `.filter`

Answer (score 3):

```
ABC.filter(function(item) {
  return item.id === 'whatever you want to check'
})
```

Array.prototype.filter iterates over an array and returns a new filtered array based on a function you provide. That function receives the array item, index and the array as parameters. Your function must return true or false. If an iteration returns true it's kept and if it returns false it's removed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

---

Edit

It sounds like you're actually trying to find a single item in an array and access a property on it. So if you know your id:

```
var curId = 'HOME'
```

Then you can just find the item that has that id:

```
var item = ABC.find(function(item) {
  return item.id === curId
})
```

If there's a match you can access the key you want:

```
item && item['elements' + curId.substr(0, 1) + curId.substr(1).toLowerCase()]
```

Comment: I had hoped the OP would figure this out on their own, but you've given a good example. Now could you add an explanation as to what it does?

Comment: I try this, I will give you a feedback about result :P

Comment: I'm trying to include a translation of this code in my angularjs file. (fulthermore I have to change something like "item.id" because my id is one of the items that I called in my ng repeat and not a "son")

Comment: Please provide some more complete code then so we can get a clear picture of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The situation is this: I have to include a tutorial code to my home page with ID = home. Furthermore I have another tutorial to include in another section of the website with ID = payment. So:

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't really clarify anything. Can you provide an actual code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

```
_.filter(ABC, { 'id': 'good' });
```